# Is there an R function to implement column variables row by row in an already existing function and loop that?

Tags: r, loops, dataset

:)

The title is rather complicated but so is the problem. **Short:** I have a command in R to print a T-Value for a spefific raw-value and a specific age-value. So **raw + age = T-Value**. I have to do that for 999 subjects. The data is in jamovi and R. So thats free of choice.

The R-package is cNORM and the used command is: *predictNorm(Raw,Age,model1,minNorm = 0,maxNorm = 100)*

It usually seems not intended to put in the column names. **So usually the program expects you to fill in sole values.** Is there a way to write a sort of loop that iterates through the two rows "raw" and "age" and fills  the nescessary spaces of the command with those values row by row? And in the best case prints it directly?

If something is still unclear, feel free to ask. I am glad for any help.

Comment: It's ot clear what data structure you are working with. If its a dataframe named `d` then just `d$Tval <- d$raw+d$age`. It' entirely unclear what involvement an R package might have in all this unless it creates a data structure that doesn't behave like a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My "raw+age = T-Value" was unclear, I'm sorry. So I have a dataframe with 138 columns and 999 rows (Rows for subjects). And I am using the command "predictNorm" of that package. So instead of repeating the "PredictNorm" command 999 times with different values of the 2 columns "raw" and "age" I would like to do that automatically. From Python I knew loops like "for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6) print i". Now I would like to prepare a loop that fills in the predictNorm command with the first 2 values, prints the result then moves to the next row and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Failed approach deleted.**

There is a family of `map` functions in the `purrr` package of the `tidyverse`.  The `map2` cluster allows you to pass 2 vectors to a function.  `map2` will execute an iteration of the function for each vector pairing.  Here is an example with `map2_dbl` which returns a numeric vector:

```
library(tidyverse)
cyl <- mtcars$cyl
mpg <- mtcars$mpg

result <- map2_dbl(cyl, mpg, function(x,y) sqrt(x * y))
result
 [1] 11.224972 11.224972  9.549869 11.331372 12.231108 10.421132 10.695794  9.879271  9.549869
[10] 10.733126 10.334409 11.454257 11.764353 11.027239  9.121403  9.121403 10.844353 11.384200
[19] 11.027239 11.644741  9.273618 11.135529 11.027239 10.315038 12.393547 10.449880 10.198039
[28] 11.027239 11.242775 10.871982 10.954451  9.252027
```

So in your case the formula would be

```
library(tidyverse)
raw <- df$raw
age <- df$age
result <- map2_dbl(raw, age, function(x, y) predictNorm(x,y, model1,minNorm = 0,maxNorm = 100)
```

`map2` uses the anonymous function, `function(x, y)` to place your vector pairs in the right positions of the `predictNorm` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if i got it right, I have to create like 2 elements that contain the content of the two columns? Like: 

raw <- data$raw and 
age <- data$age

and then do like:

predictNorm(raw,age,minNorm=XX,maxNorm=XX)?

Did I get it correct? :)

Comment: Sorry for second comment. I tried it and it gave me "Fehler in predictNorm(Rohwert, Alter, model1, minNorm = 0, maxNorm = 100) : 
  Please check raw and A value. Both have to be either single values or vectors of the same length." So it wont just skip rows when one of each values is a missing? I have to eliminate affected rows i suppose. Is that correct?

Comment: Right.  Vectors have to be the same length.  You can filter out missing value rows first using the base R `subset` function or the `filter` function in `dplyr`

Comment: BTW, side note about "Vectors have to be the same length."  If one vector is an integer factor of the other it will also work, but process the smaller length vector the integer value times. E.g. length vector1 = 10, length vector2 = 2.  Then vector2 would be repeatedly processed 5 times in a function that uses both vectors.  But you don't want that here is your case.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer :) Somehow even though I erased rows with missing values it still gives me the same error. Might be because age is like 6.34556. Thanks Steve! :)

Comment: No, don't accept my answer if it does not work.  I'm thinking...

Comment: I did a search on `cNorm`.  A full walk through can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cNORM/vignettes/cNORM-Demo.html  I don't have the data set so can't play with it.  The `predictNorm` documentation says: Arguments: raw: The raw value, either single numeric or list of values  So you could try converting your vectors to lists.  E.g., `rawlist <- as.list(df$raw)` and `agelist <- as.list(df$age)`.  Then plug those in and see if it works.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I am impressed. I was not expecting that someone would to that much research for my problem :) Thanks for the link, I used the german version previously which is lacking the whole vector-thing. It is only written with single values. I will try to convert it right now. Wish me luck :-D

Comment: Okay: I put in the lists but it gave me out: "Fehler in coefficientPolynom[1] <- coefficientPolynom[1] - raw : 
  Ersetzung hat Länge 0" which means: Error in "..." Replacement has the Length 0." I would like to give you the data but unfortunately its information I am not allowed to share. Like its personal test results and biographical values :I

Comment: Okay, I sort of solved it (Without R though but thats okay haha) I created myself a code in Python that produces a ton of adjusted single commands (999 to be specific) that i can paste in R. Then I just take the output, put it in Python and clear it from output text. And after lots of clearing I have a Vector with 999 values left. It's a lot of work but better than copypasting like 2x999 values + copypasting 999 results :) Thanks for your effort and answers, Steve :)

Comment: See the edited answer for another method.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

predictNorm of the cNORM package accepts vectors as well for raw and age or alternatively single values. If you provide vectors for age and raw score, please be sure, both have the same number of elements.

Example, taken from the documentation (version 2.0.3) with an inbuilt dataset 'elfe':

```
cnorm.elfe <- cnorm(raw = elfe$raw, group = elfe$group)
age <- c(2.4, 2.9, 3.1, 1.9, 4.3)
raw <- c(14, 8, 19, 10, 12)
predictNorm(raw, age, cnorm.elfe)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Somehow when I tried it before it gave me errors on whatever I was doing. So therefore I used my python+r approach. But I will try it again next time with your answer in mind. Thanks! :)